# a strange FactoryConfigurationError in Bonita

Tags: groovy, jdom-2, bonita

I've coded a Java class in Eclipse in which i've a method who reads a xml file and return an ArrayList of Element.

I've exported this class as a Jar and i've added in my studio this jar with Jdom2 (to parse xml).
I call this method in a groovy script but doen't work very well.

But, when I test this script whith dependencies Jdom and my class jar, it works fine but when I run my process via Bonita portal it occurs an Error...
I've added too the javax jar from Apache but nothing..

I need your help please to solve this problem.

you can see here the start of error :

> ﻿org.bonitasoft.engine.exception.BonitaRuntimeException: USERNAME=big73 | javax.xml.parsers.FactoryConfigurationError: Provider for javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory cannot be found
>   at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ServerAPIImpl.invokeMethod(ServerAPIImpl.java:143)
>   at org.bonitasoft.engine.api.impl.ClientInterceptor.invoke(ClientInterceptor.java:88)
>   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.evaluateExpressionsOnActivityInstance(Unknown Source)
>   at org.bonitasoft.forms.server.accessor.api.ExpressionEvaluatorEngineClient.evaluateExpressionsOnActivityInstance(ExpressionEvaluatorEngineClient.java:45)

PS : sorry for my bad english, I'm not a native english speaker

Comment: It possible indicates that there's some library missing in classpath.

Comment: that's right Opal, i've added my jar in dependencies application and now my process works fine.